# Bash скрипты в Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Скрипт запускается с 4-мя параметрами. Параметры числовые. От 1 до 6, например:

```
script03.sh 1 3 4 5
```

Обозначения цветов: 1 - white, 2 - red, 3 - green, 4 - blue, 5 – purple, 6 - black.

Параметр 1 - это фон названий значений (HOSTNAME)
Параметр 2 - это цвет шрифта названий значений (HOSTNAME)
Параметр 3 - это фон значений (после знака '=')
Параметр 4 - это цвет шрифта значений (после знака '=')

Я написал так:

```
#!bin/bash

back1="\033[107m" #white
back2="\033[41m" #red
back3="\033[42m" #green
back4="\033[44m" #blue
back5="\033[45m" #purple
back6="\033[40m" #black

font1="\033[97m" #white
font2="\033[31m" #red
font3="\033[32m" #green
font4="\033[34m" #blue
font5="\033[35m" #purple
font6="\033[30m" #black
 
end='\033[0m'

echo $((back$1)) #для проверки, выводится ли значение цвета 

echo -e "$((back$1))$((front$2)) HOSTNAME = $((back$3))$((front$4))${HOSTNAME}  $end"
```

Я запускаю, к примеру, `bash ./main/sh 1 2 3 4`

Выходит ошибка:

```
line 21: \033[107m: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\033[107m")
```

На строчку для проверки.

То есть `$((back$1))` инициализируется правильно, но почему не работает тогда не пойму, какого операнда не хватает.

Comment: [Может помочь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921279/how-to-get-a-variable-value-if-variable-name-is-stored-as-string)

Comment: зачем напрямую esc-посл.? лучше через `tput setaf`

Answer (score 1):

Так это не работает, переменные не задаются динамически, на самом деле способы есть но есть и более правильный способ - массив:

```
back=(
    '' # т.к. нумерация в массиве начинается с 0 а у вас с 1
    "\033[107m" #white
    "\033[41m"  #red
    "\033[42m"  #green
    "\033[44m"  #blue
    "\033[45m"  #purple
    "\033[40m"  #black
)

font=(
    ''
    "\033[97m" #white
    "\033[31m" #red
    "\033[32m" #green
    "\033[34m" #blue
    "\033[35m" #purple
    "\033[30m" #black
)

echo -e "${back[$1]}${front[$2]} HOSTNAME = ${back[$3]}${front[$4]}$HOSTNAME  $end"
```